# Get the five closest addresses from String Array

Tags: java, android, geolocation, arrays

I have a String array in Android (Java) with 175 elements which contains addresses. Now I need to sort the five closest addresses and make it to a list, I have got it to work with one element and a Spinner.

This is my code:

```
for(String sa: stringarray) {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(sa, maxInput);

        }
```

what this does is that it run through the loop and replace every element. So if I then run

```
Address address = addresses.get(0);
```

I will get the last element in the string array.

Is there any way to store an element in like a Hashmap and compare that value to my position which I get from Googles API - getLastLocation in onConnected?

Best regards 
Antiderive

Comment: Why do you need a hashmap? Aren't you just working with geolocation?

Comment: To compare the values from the String Array, but yes I'm just working with geolocation.